# Identify with services-IRC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chat, irc, livechat, ubuntu-13.04

I used to hangout at #RubyOnRails in freenode. i have no previous experience with IRC ,michael hartl's tutorial lead me there.For past few weeks when i try to join the channel ,i get this issue

`NickServ- This nickname is registered. Please choose a different nickname, or identify via /msg NickServ identify <password>.
[12:46] == gateway/web/freenode/ip.122.172.187.129 is now your hidden host (set by syn.)
[12:46] == #rubyonrails Cannot join channel (+r) - you need to be identified with services`

so, somebody enlighten me how to identify with services..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't join `#rubyonrails` because it is `+r`, meaning only registered and identified nicknames are allowed to get in.

Did you register your nickname? If you did, you must have chosen a password when you did so. Thus, you just have to identify yourself before trying to join, as NickServ suggests, with `/msg NickServ identify your-password`.

If you never registered your nickname and all of a sudden you get this message, it means someone else registered your nickname and is using it. You didn't register it, so it's not yours, you can't claim it. There is nothing you can do besides choosing another nick (and this time register it, so that no one uses it). Change your nick by typing `/nick new-nick`, and then register. You can read about how to register with `/msg nickserv help register`. Then you can join.